# CSS Syntax Error checker in Dreamweaver?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I use Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 to code websites, are there any syntax checkers that can check for common spelling mistakes say if I spelt "position:relative;" like "postion:relative;"? Alternatively can I find something with another program?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: W3 CSS validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/  Beyond that, even Firefox's error console (shift-ctrl-j) will report on basic syntax errors (unknown properties, bad bracketing, bad units, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dreamweaver has a built in validator under "File/Validate", but it's not as good as the W3C's validator. A quick way to access it is to install the Web Developer tool bar add-on and use the validator through the tools drop down. What's cool about this tool is you can quickly validate local files too as it will automatically upload them to the W3C validator.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/